# Flutter: When might SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays value override subsequent screen overlay values

Tags: flutter, system, overlay

I have two app 'screens', **A** and **B**. Both set the `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays` in the build methods.

**A** sets as per

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);
    return WillPopScope(
    ....
```

whilst **B** sets as per

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape) {
      SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    }
    else {
      SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);
    }
    return WillPopScope(
    .....
```

Navigating from **A** to **B** in portrait works fine. If however I enter landscape in **B** flutter removes the overlays and then re-implements them immediately, ie I see the overlay disappear and reappear quickly. If I remove the overlay line completely from **A**, **B** works fine. Its like **B** is rebuilt followed by **A** but in the background. Is that a thing?

I'm navigating like so

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (mContext) => DataForm(file: _file)))
```

I've been tying to track this bug for three days. For reference overlays are set here an only here in all my code. The issue only occurs on Android.

I appreciate the first response will be '*its in your code we need to see it to solve it*'. I tried reproducing the issue in 'minimal code' to post an example but I cannot get the error to reoccur and my code is so extensive I am not sure how to show it all.

As per the title I am instead asking what scenarios might cause screen **A** overlay setting to influence screen **B** at each build.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Answering  my own question after 5 days of tracking down my bug in the hope it might help some else if future. I suspect those with experience will be thinking '*yes of course and*' so this is probably more for someone new like myself.

`SystemUIOverlay` is like a global variable that persists in the app and is implemented across screens automatically. A new screen/code can change this overlay setting at any time and know if will be applied globally and retrospectively to all screens. In my case `SystemUIOverlay` is set in `build` so any action in Screen **A** that forces a rebuild will therefore enforce the update and apply the global overlay value to **B**.

Even though Screen **A** is not showing it can continue to rebuild in the background if triggered, even when Screen **B** is opened. Therefore anything triggering a rebuild of **A** whilst **B** is open means **B** will adopt **A**'s overlay setting globally. This was the result I was seeing.

A couple of examples:

As referenced [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html), `MediaQuery.of` will cause your widget to rebuild automatically whenever the MediaQueryData changes (e.g., if the user rotates their device). So for instance if you include 'MediaQuery.of' **anywhere** in you build of Screen **A**, a build can occur even when not in focus. This rebuild of **A** then enforces it's overlay value globally which is picked up by **B** whilst it is open.

In my case rebuilding **B** set the overlay to `[]` and affected the `insets`. `MediaQuery` in **A** picked up on this, rebuilt and reset the overlay to `.values` and forced these onto **B**. And round she goes.

A periodic timer calling setState in **A** will do the same thing. I am sure there are many more examples.

So look out for and avoid any rebuild potential in **A** when it has lost focus.